# How make a dice bot in discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to create a command for my discord bot to roll dice, but I can't think of a way to allow this command to let me add a value to the roll. Example: 3d20+8

```
@bot.command()
  async def d(ctx,number):
      variable=random.randint(1,int(number)) 
      await ctx.reply(f"` {variable} ` ⟵ [{variable}] 1d{numero}")
```

Does anyone know how I would accomplish this?

Comment: What does `3d20+8` mean? Are you trying to have a die with `x` sides, numbered `y` to `y+x`?

Comment: @EricJin yes that's right

Comment: What is `number` for in the command? Is it also something like `3d20+8`? Also what does the 3 do?

Comment: @EricJin the `number` is how many sides the die will have, and the 3 is how many of this die will be rolled.
so 3 dice with 20 sides

Comment: So do you want something like them being displayed separately `#1: 9`, `#2: 29`, `#3: 11`; or a total of all of them?

Comment: kinda yes, I want it to show the result of the dice and the result of the sum separately

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this.

For readability, I made the first `dice` function unpack the input (because it's in the format `XdY+Z`). Then it goes to the second function `_dice` which does all the processing.

```py
@client.command()
async def dice(ctx, *, text: str):
    count, _, text = text.partition('d')  # eg "12d34+56" -> "12", "d", "34+56"
    size, _, offset = text.partition('+')  # eg "34+56" -> "34", "+", "56"
    try:
        count = int(count)
        size = int(size)
        offset = int(offset)
    except ValueError:
        raise commands.BadArgument('bad formatting of dice value')
    return await _dice(ctx, count, size, offset)

async def _dice(ctx, count, size, offset):
    rolls = [random.randint(offset+1, offset+size) for i in range(count)]  # eg for 20 with offset 3, generate values 4 to 23
    embed = discord.Embed(title=f'Dice for {count}d{size}+{offset}')
    embed.description = '\n'.join((f'#{i}: **{roll}**' for i, roll in enumerate(rolls)))
    embed.add_field(name='sum', value=f'total = {sum(rolls)}')
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

---

Output:

[image]

In the above you can see that `d10+10` outputs values in the range `[11,20]`, which is 10 offset from the default `[1,10]`.

Comment: thanks bro, it worked very well here, I finally managed to make it work, I was trying to do this for days and couldn't find anything on the internet

but once sorry for my english in everything i typed

Answer (score -1):

I am not familiar with discord.py in particular, but here is how I would do it in a normal file

```
import random
user_input = input("Input dice size and how many (ex. 3d6)") #here you wouldn't be asking for input, just reading it off the server
dice_number = int(user_input.split("d")[0])
dice_add = int(user_input.split("+")[1])
print(dice_add)
dice_sides = int(user_input.strip(str(dice_number)).strip(str(dice_add)).strip("d").strip("+"))
total_number = 0
for i in range(dice_number):
  total_number += random.randint(1, dice_sides)
total_number += dice_add
print(total_number)

total_number = 0
for i in range(dice_number):
  total_number += random.randint(1, dice_sides)
total_number += int(dice[2])
print(total_number)
```

in the case you want to subtract as well, just make the input something like 4d12+-6 for a -6 modifier

Comment: I changed a few things to fit discord.py but no success, still thanks

and again sorry for my english

Answer (score -1):

Here's how I would write it:

```py
import random
import re

from discord.ext import commands

# ...

@bot.command()
async def roll(ctx: commands.Context, cmd: str):
    num, sides, offset = map(lambda s: int(s), re.split(r"[d+]+", user_input))
    total = sum(random.randint(1, sides) for _ in range(num)) + offset
    # do what you want with the total
```

Now, there is a bit going on here, so I'll try to break it down.

- `re.split(r"[d+]+")` takes our `user_input` and splits it at one or more delimiters: 'd' and '+'.
- `map` takes these split values and converts them all to `int`s.
- The `sum` section is a more Pythonic way of doing the same action `num` times and adding up the results. We add the `offset` back on at the end.

I don't really understand what you're trying to achieve with the format, so I'm going to leave that up to you.

Comment: thanks for trying to help me, but this  `user_input`  is giving an error, do I have to import anything else?
(I'm not very good at programming, I'm just trying to build a bot to improve my rpg table)

again sorry my english

Comment: Ignore the `user_input` thing. Your bot takes in `cmd`, which is everything you pass to it in the `roll` command. Everything after "/roll" (or whatever your prefix is) is the command.

Comment: thank you so much man, i finally got it

but once sorry for my english in everything i typed